# I cannot reference parent in my constructor method

Tags: actionscript-3

```
public function Browser(){

                var chrome:chromeicon = new chromeicon();

                this.parent.addChild(chrome);
                chrome.y = 745;
                chrome.x = 220;



    }
```

I notice that  I cannot reference the parent of the class in the constructor method or any method that is instantiated when I add the object. There must be a way around this problem, but since I'm new to oop I don't know it.

Comment: Display Object doesn't have a parent until it is added to the display list. So if your Browser object is not yet added to the display list it's parent is null. NOTE and SUGGESTION: You're not trying to do something of good practice here so try adding your chrmeIcon inside your Browser object or place it from Browser object's parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because a "parent" refers to parent on list of displayed objects. It means that as long as this object is not added as a child to other object, it has no parent, I'm not sure if they need to be added to stage also. You can go around this problem by adding to constructor a listener:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _myFunction);
```

and then construct a function:

```
private function _myFunction(e:Event) :void {
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _myFunction);
    // here you will be sure that your object has a parent that you can refer to, that will be a parent on the display list.
}
```

Comment: I've added the object like so onto the stage: var aBrowser:Browser = new Browser(); addChild(aBrowser); Does this not make it a child of the stage now?

Comment: Yest it's not a child of stage, but look at the code. The constructor of a Browser object is called before adding it to stage. So if you try to reach it's parent in the constructor you'll get null. Statement new Browser() executes the constructor of that object and only after that you add it to stage.

Comment: If there's no other way to do it, do it as Zaroda suggested. That's the best way if you want to reach Browser object's parent.

Comment: But look - your constructor code is executing BEFORE you added object to display list. It means it doesn't have parent yet when it referencing it in the constructor.

Comment: Note if you just need your parent, and not to be on the actual stage, you can use the `ADDED` event instead